# Azure Devops NPM Please change your working directory to a valid directory

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-devops, npm-install

I am trying to build a project with npm run-script build

my package.json is like this

```
{
  "name": "isomorphic",
  "version": "2.6.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.17",
    "antd": "^3.0.3",
    "antd-local-icon": "^0.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clone": "^2.1.1",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "postcss-inline-rtl": "^0.9.8",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-adal": "^0.4.17",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.16.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-placeholder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-sidebar": "^2.3.2",
    "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^8.0.6",
    "react-throttle": "^0.3.0",
    "react-window-size-listener": "^1.0.10",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.2.5",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.1",
    "styled-theme": "^0.3.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

and my build definition is like this
[image]

However I still get this error:
Azure Devops NPM Please change your working directory to a valid directory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the field **Working folder that contains package.json** you specified the file itself and not the folder path. you just need to put the folder path that contains the `package.json`.

[image]

Comment: ##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\a\1\s\${Build.SourcesDirectory}'

Comment: Replace the ‘{}’ with ‘()’

Comment: thanks, but now I have lots of other errors, its very strange because locally the same commands works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231041/how-to-create-an-azure-devops-buildpipeline-for-a-react-app

Comment: You're welcome. I will check your another question.

Answer (score 8):

Just leave empty "Working folder with package.json" field

[image: Just leave empty "Working folder with package.json" field]

Comment: This works. I was giving the js file instead of directory.

Answer (score 0):

added "Node Tool Installer" with version "6.9.1"
added "Npm" with the following custom command "install -g npm@latest"