# Azure CI pipelines Angular app build failed

Tags: angular, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I've spent a lot of hours to find a solution and already made 72 runs but things are not working for me. I'm using Azure devops pipelines. Here is the log. Why it is removing a directory? Could that be the problem?

```
##[debug]customRegistry=useNpmrc
##[debug]Using registries in .npmrc
##[debug]customEndpoint=null
##[debug]customRegistry=useNpmrc
##[debug]which 'npm'
##[debug]found: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\6.17.1\x64\npm.cmd'
##[debug]which 'npm'
##[debug]found: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\node\6.17.1\x64\npm.cmd'
##[debug]System.Debug=true
##[debug]Agent.BuildDirectory=D:\a\1
##[debug]rm -rf D:\a\1\npm
##[debug]removing directory
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: Please change your working directory to a valid directory
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Please change your working directory to a valid directory
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Please change your working directory to a valid directory
```

YAML

```js
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 6.x'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Use npm @latest'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install -g npm@latest'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@0
  displayName: 'npm build'
  inputs:
    cwd: myapp/package.json
    command: custom
    arguments: 'run prod-build-dev'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: app'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: app
```

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: Without your pipeline definition it will be nearly impossible to help with this.

Comment: Seems the task's trying to remove the directory but it can not found directory. Please share the pipeline so that we can see if the directly is set properly. Also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55234287/12722389) and [this one](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/670#issuecomment-386099498).

Comment: It's weird that it worked when I set the npm build task version to 0 and the Node.js tool installer task version to 0.

Comment: The cwd should specify the folder where the script is located instead of the script file itself which you can check [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gulp?view=azure-devops#arguments) and [above thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233309/azure-devops-npm-please-change-your-working-directory-to-a-valid-directory/55234287#55234287). (You said it worked, do you mean the problem has been solved?)